# Determining Exchange Server Version in Exchange 2013 Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, activesync

Hoping someone can help me understand the following:
In an Exchange 2013 environment, when I issue the Get-ExchangeServer cmdlet in a powershell session, I see output that reports the AdminDisplayVersion property as "Version 15.0".  That is correct for a 2013 Exchange Server.

However, when I issue the Get-ActiveSyncOrganizationSettings cmdlet in the same 2013 environment, I see the ExchangeVersion property reported as "0.10 (14.0.100.0)".
That indicates a 2010 Exchange Server.

Is this a defect in one of the Microsoft cmdlets, or are these correct, but for different components of the Exchange environment?

Comment: You asked Exchange for the ActiveSync version, not the version of the software itself. I think you need to look elsewhere for a way to determine the server's version at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmnation on this, Brian.  Makes sense since the cmdlet is Get-ActiveSyncOrganizationSettings. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I created a PowerShell function to retrieve the proper version information for Exchange 2007, 2010 and 2013. My blog [post](http://binarynature.blogspot.com/2013/04/get-exchange-server-version-and-update-info-with-powershell.html) includes the code and some usage examples. Since the function is over 200 lines, I will not include it here. The following is some sample usage and output of the function:

#### Get Installed Updates (Cumulative and Update Rollups) for a Single Server

```
[PS] Get-ExchangeServerPlus -cn exch01 | select -ExpandProperty update | ft inst*,upd*,desc* -AutoSize

InstallDate UpdateBuild Description
----------- ----------- -----------
11/11/2012  8.3.279.5   Update Rollup 8-v2 for Exchange Server 2007 Service Pack 3 (KB2756497)
02/18/2013  8.3.298.3   Update Rollup 10 for Exchange Server 2007 Service Pack 3 (KB2788321)
```

#### Output All Exchange Server Object Properties with Installed Updates

```
Get-ExchangeServerPlus | % {"Name`t: $($_.Name)"; "Version`t: $($_.Version)"; "Edition`t: $($_.Edition)"; "Build`t: $($_.Build)"; "Role`t: $($_.Role)"; "OSVer`t: $($_.OSVer)"; "OSSP`t: $($_.OSSP)"; "OSArch`t: $($_.OSArch)"; if ($_.Update) { $_ | select -ExpandProperty update | ft inst*,upd*,desc* -auto } else { [Environment]::NewLine }}

...
Name    : EXCH160-02
Version : 2013
Edition : Enterprise
Build   : 15.0.620.29
Role    : MB,CAS
OSVer   : Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Datacenter
OSSP    : 0
OSArch  : 64-bit

InstallDate UpdateBuild Description
----------- ----------- -----------
04/21/2013  15.0.620.29 Microsoft Exchange Server 2013 Cumulative Update 1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get the exchange version by checking the file versions on the installed bits.  I don't have access to a 2013 environment, but I'll bet there is a few files (.exe or .dll) which will have the version.  To extract it:

```
[System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo]::GetVersionInfo("somefilepath").FileVersion
```